# regex .NET to find and replace underscores only if found between > and <

Tags: regex, replace

I have a list of strings looking like this:

```
<a href="http://blah.tld/Title_and_Title_by_-_Mr._John_Doe.html">Title_in_Title_by_-_Mr._John_Doe</a>
```

and I need to replace the `_` with a `SPACE` from the text between the `html">` and `</a>` ONLY.

so that the result to look like this:

```
<a href="http://blah.tld/Title_and_Title_by_-_Mr._John_Doe.html">Title in Title by - Mr. John Doe</a>
```

I've tried to do it in 2 steps:
first isolate that part only with `.*html">(.*)<\/a.*` & `^.*>(.*)<.*` & `.*>.*<.*` or `^.*>.*<.*`
and then do the replace but the return is always unchanged and now I'm stuck.

Any help to accomplish this is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would do it is to .split it and then .replace it, no need for regex.

```
Dim line as string = "<a href=""http://blah.tld/Title_and_Title_by_-_Mr._John_Doe.html"">Title_in_Title_by_-_Mr._John_Doe</a>"
Dim split as string() = line.split(">"c)
Dim correctString as String = split(1).replace("_"c," "c)
```

Boom done

here is the string.replace [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Though if you had to use regex, this would probably be a better way of doing it

```
Dim inputString = "<a href=""http://blah.tld/Title_and_Title_by_-_Mr._John_Doe.html"">Title_in_Title_by_-_Mr._John_Doe</a>"
Dim reg As New Regex("(?<=\>).*?(?=\<)")
Dim correctString = reg.match(inputString).value.replace("_"c, " "c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim line as string = "<a href=""http://blah.tld/Title_and_Title_by_-_Mr._John_Doe.html"">Title_and_Title_by_-_Mr._John_Doe</a>"

line = Regex.Replace(line, "(?<=\.html"">)[^<>]+(?=</a>)", _
    Function (m) m.Value.Replace("_", " "))
```

This uses a regex with lookarounds to isolate the title, and a MatchEvaluator delegate in the form of a lambda expression to replace the underscores in the title, then it plugs the result back into the string.